# What is the component cost of each Workshop item in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

A few times I've needed to go and fetch junk from an existing settlement to build turrets or other items at a new settlement (before I've set up a supply line) and I haven't been able to find a list of the workshop menu contents and the components needed to build them.

That means I have to go back and forth between the workshop menu to see the prices and the workshop inventory to take the right junk to match the components I need.

Is there a list of the workshop menu items and their component costs?

Comment: Close voter: I assume you're saying the answer is too long for the SE format. It certainly is longer than a few paragraphs, but it's not a long, wordy discussion, it's just a list of data. I was originally going to type it all up and put it on my own website, or not even put it online and just use it myself, but I thought it would be useful for other people (and the fact it only has positive votes seems to suggest I was right).

Comment: If there wasn't a list, there is now!

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer, yup :) if someone else answers with a link to a better list I'll gladly accept that answer, but this page is now the best source of that info I know of.

Comment: Apologies for the close vote. I had not realised this was a self answer, as answers are not suppose to be taken into consideration. I personally disagree with the "broad" consideration, but directly asking for the entire list would definetly fall under it (assuming you were to expect someone else to write it up for you)

Comment: @Timelord64, you do have to scroll a very long way to see it was a self-answer! :)  I tried to write the question "blind" without assuming that I also had the answer (as that seems to be the usual style for self-answer questions) but maybe I should have phrased it differently, to make it clear that the question was just setting up an answer I had already written.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Spoiler alert!** This answer includes items that are not available when you start the game and are only unlocked later. I couldn't get the spoiler markdown tag to work with headings and lists, so the unlockable items are not hidden from view - you have been warned!

This is the complete contents of the workshop menu *as I see it at the time of writing*.
There are some locked items which I haven't unlocked yet, so they aren't listed below. Please feel free to edit this answer to add things I missed.

## Structures

### Structures > Wood

#### Structures > Wood > Prefabs

- floor and roof (wood 10 steel 10) *[two variations]*
- wall and roof (wood 12 steel 10)
- hallway (wood 12 steel 10)
- hallway end (wood 14 steel 10)
- corner (wood 15 steel 12)
- wall and roof (wood 16 steel 10)
- corner (wood 20 steel 15)
- small shack (wood 30 steel 20)
- large shack (wood 40 steel 20)

#### Structures > Wood > Floors

- shack floor (wood 8 steel 2)
- shack floor (wood 7 steel 2)
- shack foundation (wood 12 concrete 3)
- shack foundation (wood 12 steel 3)
- shack stairwell (wood 12 steel 3)
- shack upper floor (wood 8 steel 2)
- floor - small (wood 3 steel 1) *[three variations]*

#### Structures > Wood > Walls

- shack wall (wood 3 steel 4)
- shack wall - doorway (wood 5 steel 3)
- shack wall - outer cap (wood 4 steel 9)
- shack wall corner (wood 12 steel 8)
- shack wall corner (wood 5 steel 8)
- shack wall corner (wood 6 steel 3)
- shack wall and roof (wood 5 steel 4)
- shack wall and roof (wood 4 steel 4 cloth 2)
- wall (wood 8 steel 5) *[two variations]*
- wall (wood 5 steel 9) *[two variations]*
- wall (wood 8 steel 5) *[three variations]*
- wall (wood 5 steel 9)
- wall - corner (wood 7 steel 3)
- wall - corner (wood 10 steel 4) *[three variations]*
- wall - corner (wood 7 steel 3) *[two variations]*
- wall - end (wood 4 steel 1) *[two variations]*
- wall - small (wood 8 steel 2) *[three variations]*
- wall - small (wood 4 steel 9) *[two variations]*

#### Structures > Wood > Roofs

- shack roof (wood 4 steel 6)
- shack roof (wood 3 steel 6)
- shack roof (wood 5 cloth 5 steel 2)
- shack roof (wood 4 steel 6)
- shack roof (wood 3 steel 6)
- shack roof (wood 5 steel 6)
- shack roof (wood 4 cloth 6 steel 2)
- shack roof (wood 4 steel 6)
- shack roof (wood 5 steel 6) *[two variations]*

#### Structures > Wood > Stairs

- shack stairs (wood 9 steel 2)
- stairs (wood 7 steel 2) *[three variations]*

#### Structures > Wood > Miscellaneous

- bridge (wood 6 steel 2)
- railing (wood 2 steel 1) *[five variations]*

#### Structures > Metal > Prefabs

- corner (steel 10 wood 4)
- doorway (steel 10 wood 4)
- floor and roof (steel 10 wood 4) *[two variations]*
- floor and roof (steel 10 wood 4) *[rounded]*
- hallway (steel 10 wood 4)
- hallway end (steel 10 wood 4)
- wall and roof (steel 12 wood 8) *[square]*
- wall and roof (steel 10 wood 4) *[rounded]*
- small metal shack (wood 20 steel 30) *[two variations]*
- large metal shack (wood 20 steel 40)

#### Structures > Metal > Walls

- wall (wood 3 steel 10) *[four variations]*
- wall - corner (wood 2 steel 8) *[six variations]*
- wall - doorway (wood 3 steel 10) *[rounded]*
- wall - doorway (wood 3 steel 10) *[square]*
- wall - small (steel 10) *[rounded]*
- wall - small (steel 10) *[square, four variations]*

#### Structures > Metal > Roofs

- shack roof (wood 3 steel 10) *[two variations]*

### Structures > Doors

- door (wood 3 steel 3) *[nine variations]*

### Structures > Fences

#### Structures > Fences > Junk Fence

- gate (wood 10 steel 15)
- junk fence (wood 15 steel 4)
- junk fence (wood 6 steel 9 rubber 4)
- junk fence (wood 10 steel 4)
- junk fence (wood 10 steel 4 rubber 2) *[two variations]*
- junk fence (wood 10 steel 4)
- junk fence (wood 6 steel 9 rubber 4)
- junk fence (wood 15 steel 4)
- junk fence (wood 2 steel 6) *[two variations]*

#### Structures > Fences > Picket Fence

*[picket fences are unlocked by finding a magazine]*

- gate (wood 3)
- picket fence post (wood 2)
- picket fence (wood 3) *[four variations]*
- picket fence (wood 6) *[two fence sections with post, two variations]*
- picket fence (wood 3) *[damaged fence section, three variations]*

#### Structures > Fences > Wire Fence

- wire fence (wood 2) [post]
- wire fence (wood 2 steel 2) *[one fence section with post]*
- wire fence (wood 2 steel 4) *[two fence sections with post]*
- wire fence (wood 4 steel 4) *[corner]*
- wire fence (wood 4 steel 2) *[gate]*
- wire fence (wood 2 steel 4) *[two fence sections with post]*
- wire fence (wood 2 steel 2) *[one fence section with post]*
- wire fence (wood 2) *[post]*
- wire fence (steel 2) *[one fence section without post]*

### Structures > Miscellaneous

- spiked pole (steel 6 skull 3)
- spiked pole (steel 6)

## Furniture

### Furniture > Beds

- bed (steel 4 cloth 5) *[four variations]*
- mattress (cloth 6)
- sleeping bag (cloth 3)

### Furniture > Chairs

- airplane seat (cloth 6 aluminum 4) *[double]*
- airplane seat (cloth 8 aluminum 5) *[triple]*
- airplane seat (cloth 4 aluminum 3) *[single]*
- bench (steel 3 wood 4)
- bench (wood 5 steel 1)
- chair (leather 4 steel 4)
- chair (cloth 4 steel 4) *[five variations]*
- chair (cloth 3 wood 5)
- chair (wood 4 cloth 4)
- chair (wood 4 cloth 2)
- chair (wood 4 plastic 1)
- chair (steel 3 cloth 1 plastic 1)
- chair (steel 3 plastic 2 cloth 2)
- chair (wood 3 cloth 5 steel 1)
- chair (wood 4 steel 1)
- chair (steel 3 cloth 2 plastic 2)
- chair (wood 4 cloth 4)
- chair (cloth 4 steel 4)
- chair (cloth 4 steel 4)
- chair (steel 4)
- couch (wood 5 cloth 9)
- couch (wood 5 cloth 10)
- couch (wood 4 cloth 7 steel 2)
- couch (wood 6 cloth 10 steel 2)
- couch (wood 6 cloth 9)
- patio chair (steel 4 plastic 2) *[unlocked by finding a magazine]*
- stool (steel 3) *[two variations]*
- stool (steel 2 wood 1)
- stool (wood 3 steel 1)
- stool (steel 4)
- stool (steel 3)
- stool (steel 5)
- stool (steel 3 plastic 1)

### Furniture > Containers

- bureau (wood 4)
- cabinet (steel 8) *[five variations]*
- cooler (steel 2 fiberglass 1)
- desk (steel 6)
- desk (steel 2 wood 4)
- dresser (wood 4 steel 2) *[two variations]*
- file cabinet (steel 4) *[three variations]*
- filing cabinet (steel 2 wood 6)
- footlocker  (steel 2 wood 4)
- metal box (steel 4)
- safe (spring 5 steel 10 gear 3)
- steamer trunk (steel 4)
- suitcase (steel 1 cloth 2)
- tool chest (steel 4)
- toolbox (steel 2)
- wooden crate (wood 3)

### Furniture > Shelves

- bookcase (wood 7 steel 1) *[tall]*
- bookcase (wood 3 steel 1) *[short]*
- magazine rack (screw 1 steel 4) *[two variations]*
- shelf (steel 4)
- shelf (wood 10 steel 3)
- shelf (wood 13 steel 4)
- wall shelf (steel 2) *[two variations]*
- wall shelf (wood 2) *[two variations]*

### Furniture > Tables

- coffee table (wood 3 steel 1)
- coffee table (wood 4)
- end table (wood 3 steel 1)
- end table (wood 4 steel 1)
- kitchen table (wood 4 steel 3) *[small]*
- kitchen table (wood 4 steel 2) *[medium]*
- kitchen table (wood 4 steel 3) *[large]*
- patio table (steel 10) *[unlocked by finding a magazine]*
- picnic table (wood 8 steel 2)
- pool table (cloth 3 wood 8 plastic 2 rubber 1 steel 2)
- table (wood 4 steel 1)
- table (wood 4)
- table (wood 4 steel 1)
- table (wood 7 steel 1)
- table (steel 5)
- table (wood 7 steel 1)
- table (wood 4 steel 1)
- table (wood 3 steel 1)
- table (wood 7 steel 1)
- table (wood 4 steel 1)
- table (wood 3 steel 1)
- table (wood 6 steel 1)
- table (wood 2 steel 2)
- table (wood 3 steel 2)
- table (wood 2 steel 2)
- table (steel 5)
- table (steel 2)
- table (wood 4)
- wet bar (wood 4 steel 1) *[two variations]*

### Furniture > Miscellaneous

- bathtub (ceramic 8 steel 2)
- bobblehead stand (screw 3 steel 4 fiberglass 3)
- counter (wood 6 steel 2)
- ottoman (wood 2 cloth 3 steel 1)
- television (steel 2 circuitry 3 wood 2 glass 2 aluminum 2) *[requires power]*
- television (steel 2 circuitry 3 wood 3 glass 2 aluminum 2) *[requires power]*
- television (steel 2 circuitry 3 wood 2 glass 2 aluminum 2) *[requires power]*
- toilet (ceramic 5 plastic 1)

## Decorations

### Decorations > Floor Coverings

- floor mats (cloth 2 rubber 1) *[six variations]*
- rug (cloth 6)
- rub (cloth 3)
- rug (cloth 4)
- rug (cloth 6) *[two variations]*

### Decoration > Wall Decorations

#### Decoration > Wall Decorations > Flags

- Brotherhood of Steel flag (cloth 5) *[unlocked by completing quests]*
- Minutemen flag (cloth 5) *[unlocked by completing quests]*
- U.S. flag (cloth 5)

#### Decoration > Wall Decorations > Mounted Creatures

- mounted brahmin heads (wood 1 cloth 2 brahmin skull 2)
- mounted mirelurk claw (wood 1 cloth 1 mirelurk meat 1)
- mounted molerat head (wood 1 cloth 1 mole rat meat 1 mole rat teeth 1)
- mounted radstag heads (wood 1 cloth 2 radstag meat 1)

#### Decoration > Wall Decorations > Paintings

- painting (wood 5) *[20 variations]*

#### Decoration > Wall Decorations > Signs

- signs (steel 4) *[11 variations]*

#### Decoration > Wall Decorations > Miscellaneous

- basketball hoop (steel 4)
- eat-o-tronic (steel 4 glass 2)

### Decorations > Miscellaneous

- ashtray (steel 4)
- basketball hoop (steel 6)
- cigarette machine (steel 4 rubber 1)
- crib (steel 1 wood 5 cloth 2)
- doghouse (wood 3 steel 1)
- grill (steel 4 rubber 1)
- ice cooler (steel 4 rubber 1)
- milk vending machine (steel 4 rubber 1)
- Nuka-Cola machine (steel 2 rubber 1 plastic 2)
- radio (circuitry 1 plastic 2 copper 1 rubber 2) *[Diamond City radio]*
- radio (circuitry 1 plastic 2 copper 1 rubber 2) *[classical radio]*
- sign (steel 4 rubber 1)
- trash bin (steel 4 rubber 1)
- trash can (steel 4)
- jukebox (circuitry 2 plastic 2 copper 2 glass 2 steel 2) *[requires 2 power]*

## Power

### Power > Generators

- generator - small (gear 2 steel 4 rubber 2 copper 2 ceramic 1) *[produces 3 power]*
- generator - medium (screw 3 gear 3 steel 7 rubber 3 copper 3 ceramic 1) *[produces 5 power]*
- generator - large (gear 5 screw 5 rubber 4 copper 10 aluminum 12 nuclear material 3) *[produces 10 power, requires Science! perk rank 1]*
- generator - windmill (steel 15 copper 4 aluminum 10 gear 2) *[produces 3 power]*

### Power > Connectors & Switches

- power pylon (copper 2 wood 2 ceramic 1 steel 1)
- power pylon - large (copper 4 ceramic 3 steel 8 rubber 1) *[requires power]*
- power conduit (copper 2 ceramic 2 steel 2) *[three variations]*
- switched power pylon (copper 3 wood 2 steel 2 ceramic 1 rubber 1) *[requires power]*
- switched power pylon - large (copper 5 steel 9 ceramic 3 rubber 1) *[requires power]*
- switch (steel 2 copper 1 rubber 1) *[requires power]*
- pressure plate (copper 3 steel 3 spring 2) *[requires power]*
- laser tripwire (fiber optics 2 steel 4 crystal 1 fusion cell 6) *Transmits power when disarmed. Use a connected terminal to access additional functionality.* *[two variations, requires power]*
- delayed off switch (copper 2 wood 2 ceramic 1) *Stops transmitting power after a short delay. Use a connected terminal to change the delay.* *[two variations, requires power]*
- interval switch  (copper 2 wood 2 ceramic 1) *Switches on and off repeatedly. Use a connected  terminal to change the on/off internals.* *[requires power]*
- power counter (copper 1 wood 1 ceramic 1 steel 2) *Transmits power briefly after cycling power 10 times. Use a connected terminal to change the max count.* *[requires power]*

### Power > Lights

- lightbulb (glass 1 copper 1 steel 2) *[requires power]*
- industrial wall light (glass 1 copper 1 steel 2) *[requires power]*
- construction light (glass 2 copper 1 steel 4) *[requires power]*
- ceiling fan (glass 1 copper 1 gear 1 wood 1 steel 2) *[requires power]*
- lamp (glass 1 copper 1 steel 2) *[requires power]*
- mirror ball (glass 6 copper 1 steel 2) *[requires power]*
- strobe light (glass 1 copper 1 steel 2 circuitry 1) *[requires power]*

### Power > Miscellaneous

- recruitment radio beacon (circuitry 2 crystal 2 copper 6 steel 10 ceramic 3 rubber 1) *Attracts new settlers to your settlement when turned on.* *[requires 1 power]*
- terminal (rubber 2 copper 2 circuitry 2 aluminum 4) *Access additional functionality on connected objects.* *[requires 1 power]*
- lightbox (glass 1 copper 1 steel 2) *Use a connected terminal to access additional functionality.* *[requires 1 power]*
- powered speaker (copper 1 wood 1 steel 2 circuitry 1) *Plays a musical tone when powered up. Use a connected terminal to change the pitch.* *[requires 1 power]*

## Defense

### Defense > Guard Posts

- guard post (wood 10 steel 4) *[requires worker, produces 2 defense]*
- guard tower (wood 12 steel 6) *[requires worker, produces 2 defense]*

### Defense > Turrets

- machinegun turret (steel 8 circuitry 1 gear 2 oil 2) - guard post (wood 10 steel 4) *[produces 5 defense]*
- heavy machinegun turret (steel 10 circuitry 2 gear 2 oil 4) *[produces 8 defense, requires Gun Nut perk rank 1]*
- laser turret (aluminum 5 circuitry 3 screw 3 fiber optics 4 gear 2 nuclear material 2 steel 5 glass 3) *[requires 2 power, produces 8 defense, requires Science! perk rank 1]*
- shotgun turret (aluminum 4 circuitry 5 screw 4 gear 4 oil 5 steel 6) *[requires 2 pwoer, produces 8 defense, requires Gun Nut perk rank 2]*
- spotlight (circuitry 1 screw 1 gear 2 steel 6 oil 1 glass 2) *[requires 2 power, produces 2 defense]*
- heavy laser turret (cyrstal 4 aluminum 7 circuitry 4 screw 4 fiber optics 4 gear 3 nuclear material 4 steel 3) *[requires 2 power, produces 12 defense, requires Science! perk rank 3]*
- missile turret (aluminum 6 circuitry 6 screw 5 oil 6 steel 6) *[requires 2 power, produces 15 defense, requires Gun Nut perk rank 3]*

### Defense > Traps

- Tesla arc (steel 2 copper 3 circuitry 1) Shoots electricity when powered up. *[requires power, produces 2 defense]*
- radiation emitter (screw 2 nuclear material 3 lead 2 steel 2) *[requires power, produces 2 defense]*
- flamethrower trap (screw 2 rubber 4 aluminum 4 oil 6) Shoots flame when powered up. *[requires power, produces 3 defense]*

## Resources

### Resources > Water

- water pump (concrete 1 steel 4 gear 1) *Can only be placed in dirt.* *[produces 3 water]*
- water purifier (oil 2 ceramic 2 rubber 5 copper 2 steel 10 cloth 2) *Must be placed in the water.* *[requires 2 power, produces 10 water]*
- water purifier - industrial (oil 4 ceramic 2 rubber 10 copper 4 steel 20 cloth 4 screw 6) *Must be placed in the water.* *[requires 5 power, produces 40 water]*

### Resources > Food

- carrot (carrot 1) *Can only be placed in dirt.* *[requires worker, produces 0.5 food]*
- corn (corn 1) *Can only be placed in dirt.* *[two variations, requires worker, produces 0.5 food]*
- gourd (gourd 1) *Can only be placed in dirt.* *[requires worker, produces 0.5 food]*
- melon (melon 1) *Can only be placed in dirt.* *[requires worker, produces 0.5 food]*
- mutfruit plant (mutfruit 1) *Can only be placed in dirt.* *[requires worker, produces 1 food]*
- razorgrain (razorgrain 1) *Can only be placed in dirt.* *[two variations, requires worker, produces 0.5 food]*
- tato plant (tato 1) *Can only be placed in dirt.* *[two variations, requires worker, produces 0.5 food]*

### Resources > Miscellaneous

- scavenging station (wood 5 steel 3) *Extra scavenging production.* *[requires worker]*
- brahmin feed trough (steel 2 ceramic 8) *Brahmin will tend to stay near their feed trough.*
- bell (wood 4 steel 4) *Ring to gather nearby settlers.*
- siren (copper 5 steel 9 ceramic 3 rubber 1) *Alerts nearby settlers to danger when triggered.* *[requires 1 power]*
- fast travel target (cloth 2 rubber 1) *Only one per location. Moves the fast travel arrival point.*

## Stores

*[all stores require Local Leader perk rank 2]*

### Stores > Trader

- trading stand (wood 5 bottlecap 300 steel 3) *[requires worker]*
- trading shop (wood 5 bottlecap 600 steel 3) *[requires worker]*
- trading emporium (wood 5 bottlecap 1500 steel 3) *[requires worker, requires Cap Collector perk rank 2]*

### Stores > Armor

- armor stand (wood 5 bottlecap 500 steel 3) *[requires worker]*
- armor shop (wood 5 bottlecap 1000 steel 3) *[requires worker]*
- armor emporium (wood 5 bottlecap 3000 steel 3) *[requires worker, requires Cap Collector perk rank 2]*

### Stores > Weapons

- weapons stand (wood 5 bottlecap 500 steel 3) *[requires worker]*
- weapons shop (wood 5 bottlecap 1000 steel 3) *[requires worker]*
- weapons emporium (wood 5 bottlecap 3000 steel 3) *[requires worker, requires Cap Collector perk rank 2]*

### Stores > Food and Drink

- drink stand (wood 5 bottlecap 250 steel 3) *[requires worker]*
- bar (wood 5 bottlecap 500 steel 3) *[requires worker]*
- restaurant (wood 5 bottlecap 1500 steel 3) *[requires worker, requires Cap Collector perk rank 2]*

### Stores > Clinic

- first aid station (wood 5 bottlecap 0 steel 3) *[requires worker]*
- bar (wood 5 bottlecap 1200 steel 3) *[requires worker, requires Medic perk rank 1]*
- restaurant (wood 5 bottlecap 1800 steel 3) *[requires worker, requires Cap Collector perk rank 2]*

### Stores > Clothing

- clothing stand (wood 5 bottlecap 200 steel 3) *[requires worker]*
- clothing shop (wood 5 bottlecap 400 steel 3) *[requires worker]*
- clothing emporium (wood 5 bottlecap 1000 steel 3) *[requires worker, requires Cap Collector perk rank 2]*

## Crafting

*[all crafting stations and workbenches require Local Leader perk rank 2]*

- armor workbench (wood 3 gear 5 spring 4 screw 4 aluminum 8)
- chemistry station (wood 8 steel 6 glass 6 rubber 3 screw 4)
- chemistry station (wood 3 steel 6 copper 4 rubber 3 screw 3 glass 4)
- cooking station (steel 5 concrete 3 wood 3 screw 3)
- cooking station (steel 4 gear 3 wood 2 screw 2)
- cooking stove (steel 4 gear 3 wood 2 screw 2)
- power armor station (gear 6 oil 4 screw 4 plastic 4 aluminum 12 fiberglass 6 circuitry 3) *[requires Armorer perk rank 1]*
- weapons workbench (wood 4 gear 4 screw 3 aluminum 7 rubber 4)
- weapons workbench (wood 2 gear 3 screw 4 aluminum 6 rubber 6)

Comment: How long did it take to compile this list? Thank you for compiling it, though!

Comment: @WiZΔRD No idea, I don't even remember doing it!